# Post/Pre-Increment confusion

Tags: java, post-increment, pre-increment, unary-operator

From what I understand, if I have a variable k = 5, and I do ++k, the new value of k = 6. If I do k++, the value remains 5 until k appears the second time in the program, which is when it is changed to 6. For e.g:

```
k = 5;
System.out.println(k++); //prints 5, but now that k has appeared the second time, its value is incremented to 6
System.out.println(k); //prints 6
```

However, in this code:

```
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        int x = 0;
        x++;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
```

In the loop, though the variable i appears for the 2nd time(in System.out.println(i)), its value remains at 0. But for x, when it appears for the second time( in System.out.println(x); ) its value is incremented.
Why? I'm confused about how post and pre-increment work.

Comment: the for loop runs before doing the i++

Comment: Oh, yeah. "How do the post increment (i++) and pre increment (++i) operators work in Java?" already has the answer to my question. Sorry for posting. Can a moderator please delete this question?

Comment: Sorry I marked as duplicate. Your question was actually about when the post increment happens in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code

```
    for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

firstly the variable i is initialized to 0, it then checks if it satisfies the condition i < 10 and print the variable and lastly increments the variable i.

This is how the for loop works.

In the second piece of code you have written, it increments the variable x and lastly prints the value of x.